# Xquery TSQL: How to retrieve element data when traversing parents nodes with multiple xmlns, xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xml-namespaces

I need to retrieve the 'true' value in processquotedetail element.

What xmlnamespaces would i have to provide, and specify in an outer apply in order to successfully retrieve 'true'

I have changed the xmlns: values

I have tried the below and several other slight alternatives, all of which are returning null. Can you explain why the below doesn't work, and why what does work, does?

Thank you

**The query:**

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('web.servivces.com"' as  pmq,
                    'www.test.com/' as q,
                    'www.test.com/request/' as r )

select 
x.RequestID,       dc.tx.value('pmq:Control[1]/pmq:ProcessQuoteDetail[1]','nvarchar(max)')
dc.tx.value('Control[1]/ProcessQuoteDetail[1]','nvarchar(max)')

from [dbo].[uvw_decompressXML_DC_Quote] x  

outer apply x.DCRequest.nodes('server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy
r:AdditionalData/r:KeyValuePair/q:Key/q:Value/pmq:PMQuoteData') as dc(tx)
```

**The XML:**

```
XML: 
<server>
  <requests>
    <Session.loginRq userName="admin" password="admin" />
    <Session.setDocumentRq>
      <session>
        <data>
          <MotorQuoteID />
          <TransactionReason>Rating</TransactionReason>
          <policy>
            <AdditionalData xmlns="www.test.com/request/" 
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <KeyValuePair>
                <Key xmlns="www.test.com/">AggregatorXML</Key>
                <Value xmlns="www.test.com/">
                  <PMQuoteData xmlns="web.servivces.com">
                    <Control>
                      <ProcessQuoteDetail>true</ProcessQuoteDetail>
```

Comment: Please provide your XML in its entirety.

Comment: It is obscenely long, will the closing tags suffice?

Comment: It should be sufficient to know that server is the root element. If it's not you need to show all the enclosing elements or confirm none have any namespace declarations.

Answer (score 0):

> SQL

```
-- DDL and data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, xmlData XML NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
('<server>
    <requests>
        <Session.loginRq userName="admin" password="admin"/>
        <Session.setDocumentRq>
            <session>
                <data>
                    <MotorQuoteID/>
                    <TransactionReason>Rating</TransactionReason>
                    <policy>
                        <AdditionalData xmlns="www.test.com/request/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                            <KeyValuePair>
                                <Key xmlns="www.test.com/">AggregatorXML</Key>
                                <Value xmlns="www.test.com/">
                                    <PMQuoteData xmlns="web.servivces.com">
                                        <Control>
                                            <ProcessQuoteDetail>true</ProcessQuoteDetail>
                                        </Control>
                                    </PMQuoteData>
                                </Value>
                            </KeyValuePair>
                        </AdditionalData>
                    </policy>
                </data>
            </session>
        </Session.setDocumentRq>
    </requests>
</server>');
-- DDL and data population, end

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('web.servivces.com' as ns3,
                    'www.test.com/' as ns2,
                    'www.test.com/request/' as ns1 )
SELECT tbl.id, col.value('(ns3:ProcessQuoteDetail)[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') as [ProcessQuoteDetail]
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY tbl.XMLDATA.nodes('/server/requests/Session.setDocumentRq/session/data/policy/ns1:AdditionalData/ns1:KeyValuePair/ns2:Value/ns3:PMQuoteData/ns3:Control') tab(col);
```